# group by not grouping aggregate?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, aggregate-functions, postgresql-9.3

Let's say I am trying to build an opinion poll app, such that I can create a template of an opinion poll, give it multiple sections/questions, assign multiple people to different copies of a given question, create varying measures (happyness, succesfulness, greenness) and assign different questions different weights to apply to all of these measures.

Something like so:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE opinion_poll_templates (
  id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE opinion_poll_instances (
  id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  template_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES opinion_poll_templates(id)
);

CREATE TABLE section_templates (
  id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  opinion_poll_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES opinion_poll_templates(id)
);

CREATE TABLE section_instances (
  id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  opinion_poll_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES opinion_poll_instances(id),
  template_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES section_templates(id)
);

CREATE TABLE question_templates (
  id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  section_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES section_templates(id)
);

CREATE TABLE measure_templates (
  id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  opinion_poll_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES opinion_poll_templates(id)
);

CREATE TABLE answer_options (
  id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  question_template_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES question_templates(id),
  weight FLOAT8
);

CREATE TABLE question_instances (
  id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  template_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES question_templates(id),
  opinion_poll_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES opinion_poll_instances(id),
  section_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES section_instances(id),
  answer_option_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES answer_options(id),
  contributor_id INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE measure_instances (
  id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  opinion_poll_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES opinion_poll_instances(id),
  template_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES measure_templates(id),
  total_score INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE scores (
  id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  question_template_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES question_templates(id),
  measure_template_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES measure_templates(id),
  score INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

Now let's say I am interested in the per measureInstance (per measure assigned to an opinion poll) cross question, cross user average?

```
WITH weighted_score AS (
  SELECT AVG(answer_options.weight), measure_instances.id
  FROM question_instances
  INNER JOIN answer_options ON question_instances.template_id = answer_options.question_template_id
  INNER JOIN scores ON question_instances.template_id = scores.question_template_id
  INNER JOIN measure_instances ON measure_instances.template_id=scores.measure_template_id
  WHERE measure_instances.opinion_poll_id = question_instances.opinion_poll_id
  GROUP BY measure_instances.id
)
UPDATE measure_instances
SET total_score=(SELECT avg FROM weighted_score
WHERE weighted_score.id = measure_instances.id)*100
RETURNING total_score;
```

This seems to not only not group as expected, but produced incorrect results.

Why is the result an integer rather then a float? Why is the result not being grouped by measure instance instead being identical across all?
And why is the result incorrect for any of them?

A demonstration: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/dcce8/1

EDIT: In working through explaining exactly what I wanted, I realized the source of my problem was that I was simply adding percentages, rather then normalizing across questions as a percentage.

My new and improved sql is:

```
WITH per_question_percentage AS (  
  SELECT SUM(answer_options.weight)/COUNT(question_instances.id) percentage, question_templates.id qid, opinion_poll_instances.id oid
  FROM question_instances
  INNER JOIN answer_options ON question_instances.answer_option_id = answer_options.id
  INNER JOIN question_templates ON question_templates.id = question_instances.template_id
  INNER JOIN opinion_poll_instances ON opinion_poll_instances.id = question_instances.opinion_poll_id
  GROUP BY question_templates.id, opinion_poll_instances.id
), max_per_measure AS (
  SELECT SUM(scores.score), measure_instances.id mid, measure_instances.opinion_poll_id oid
  FROM measure_instances
  INNER JOIN scores ON scores.measure_template_id=measure_instances.template_id
  GROUP BY measure_instances.id, measure_instances.opinion_poll_id
), per_measure_per_opinion_poll AS (
  SELECT per_question_percentage.percentage * scores.score score, measure_instances.id mid, measure_instances.opinion_poll_id oid
  FROM question_instances
  INNER JOIN scores ON question_instances.template_id = scores.question_template_id
  INNER JOIN measure_instances ON measure_instances.template_id = scores.measure_template_id
  INNER JOIN max_per_measure ON measure_instances.id = max_per_measure.mid
  INNER JOIN per_question_percentage ON per_question_percentage.qid = question_instances.template_id
  WHERE measure_instances.opinion_poll_id = question_instances.opinion_poll_id AND question_instances.opinion_poll_id = per_question_percentage.oid
  GROUP BY measure_instances.id, measure_instances.opinion_poll_id, per_question_percentage.percentage, scores.score
) 
UPDATE measure_instances
SET total_score = subquery.result*100
FROM (SELECT SUM(per_measure_per_opinion_poll.score)/max_per_measure.sum result, per_measure_per_opinion_poll.mid, per_measure_per_opinion_poll.oid
      FROM  max_per_measure, per_measure_per_opinion_poll
      WHERE per_measure_per_opinion_poll.mid = max_per_measure.mid 
      AND per_measure_per_opinion_poll.oid = max_per_measure.oid
      GROUP BY max_per_measure.sum, per_measure_per_opinion_poll.mid, per_measure_per_opinion_poll.oid)
      AS subquery(result, mid, oid)
WHERE measure_instances.id = subquery.mid
AND measure_instances.opinion_poll_id = subquery.oid
RETURNING total_score;
```

Is this canonical sql? Is there anything I should be aware of with this kind of CTE chaining (or otherwise)? Is there a more efficient way to achieve the same thing?

Comment: Q1: `measure_instances.TotalScore`is defined as an `INTEGER`. Q2: It **is** correctly grouped by `measure_instances.id`. Q3: Because you do something wrong in your joins? Run the `SELECT` within the CTE standalone any remove the `AVG`/`GROUP BY` and check the detail rows.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit long for a comment.

I don't understand the questions.

*Why is the result an integer rather then a float?*

Because `measure_instances.total_score` is an integer and that is what the `returning` clause is returning.

*Why is the result not being grouped by measure instance instead being identical across all?*

When I run the CTE independently, the values are 0.45.  The data and logic dictate the same values.

*And why is the result incorrect for any of them?*

I think you mean "for all of them".  In any case, the results look correct to me.

Answer (score 1):

If you run this query against data in your demo:

```
SELECT 
    answer_options.weight, measure_instances.id
FROM 
    question_instances
INNER JOIN 
    answer_options ON question_instances.template_id = answer_options.question_template_id
INNER JOIN 
    scores ON question_instances.template_id = scores.question_template_id
INNER JOIN 
    measure_instances ON measure_instances.template_id=scores.measure_template_id
WHERE 
    measure_instances.opinion_poll_id = question_instances.opinion_poll_id
ORDER BY
    2;
```

You will get:

```
| weight | id |
|--------|----|
|    0.5 |  1 |
|   0.25 |  1 |
|   0.25 |  1 |
|   0.75 |  1 |
|    0.5 |  1 |
|   0.75 |  2 |
|    0.5 |  2 |
|   0.25 |  2 |
|    0.5 |  2 |
|   0.25 |  2 |
```

If you calculate averages by hand, you will get:
For **id=1** ==> 0.5+0.25+0.25+0.75 + 0.5 = 2.25 ==> 2.25 / 5 = **0.45**
For **id=2** ==> 0.75 + 0.5 + 0.25 + 0.5 + 0.25 = 2.25 ==> 2.25 / 5 = **0.45**

It seems to me, that this query is working perfectly.

Please explain why these results are wrong to you, and what do you expect to get from the above data and query?

Comment: Thank you for trying to get me to explain this. In doing so, I have arrived at what is actually a solution. My problem was that I was not normalizing my results across measures. See my question for an update (in the edit).